# Save Excel attachment as .txt - opened with a vba macro from Outlook 2010

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have VBA code in Outlook which downloads an Excel attachment of specific emails. Once saved I open the Excel file and change a couple of things, and then I would like to save it as .txt instead of excel.

This is my code:

```
' Save the attachment as a file.
objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
'Open the attachment file
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Workbooks.Open (strFile)
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.Workbooks.Item(1).activesheet.cells(1, 1).Value = "whatever"

**xlApp.SaveAs strFile, FileFormat:=xlText**
xlApp.Workbooks.Close
```

Does anyone know how to save that Excel in VBA on outlook?

---

Sorry if a was not as clear as i wanted.

The part that is not working is:

xlApp.SaveAs strFile, FileFormat:=xlText

I'm running this from Outlook 2010, and i don't understand why is not working when i'm trying to save the excel as a plain text (wit tabs delimited), am i doing something wrong?

Thanks all for your responses.

Comment: What is not working with this?

Comment: @JorgeRoldanSilla - What's not working about this code, and what do you mean by "How to save that excel in vba on outlook"? I assume English isn't your first language - maybe find a friend who can translate what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This will save it as a csv.  I'm not sure you really want a plain text file as you would lose all column structure..

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="C:\Temp\" & ActiveSheet.name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

Here is a function I wrote at some point to export a whole workbook.  It puts each worksheet into it's own text file.

```
Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String
Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
Dim CurrentFormat As Long
Dim cell As Range

    CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
    ' Store current details for the workbook
    SaveToDirectory = "C:\Temp\"

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        'This was a check on the worksheet name for excluding some worksheets that I didn't want to export
        'If ws.name <> "Instructions" And ws.name <> "Parameters" And ws.name <> "BI Data & Worksheet" Then

            'This makes the current sheet its own workbook so it can be saved.
            Sheets(ws.name).Copy

            'Not sure what I was doing here
            'For Each cell In [b:b]
            'If cell.Value = "~" Then cell.ClearContents
            ''put any value you want here
            'Next cell


            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=SaveToDirectory & ws.name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
            ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            ThisWorkbook.Activate
        'End If
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ' Temporarily turn alerts off to prevent the user being prompted
    '  about overwriting the original file.
End Sub
```